# How can we get current product price in observer.php

Tags: magento-1.7, product, price, event-observer, model

i want set some discount on price with observer

```
class Brain_Priceedit_Model_Observer {

    public function _construct()
      {
      }

    public function getNewPrice()
      {
        //Your new functionality here
        //
        $newprice = '10';

        return $newprice;
      }

     public function updatePrice( Varien_Event_Observer $observer ) 
     {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
        $new_price = $this->getNewPrice();
        $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
        $quote_item->save();
      }
 }
```

i want to give 10% discount on current price

Comment: on which occation and on which event

Comment: event----sales_quote_add_item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try this and  see more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104482/programmatically-add-product-to-cart-with-price-change

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
$new_price = $this->getNewPrice();
if($quote_item->hasCustomPrice(){
$quote_item>setCustomPrice($new_price);
$quote_item>setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
$quote_item>setNoDiscount($new_price);
$quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
}
```

Hi You want to get product price then you need Load item product id and after that you can product final price

```
   $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($quote_item->getProductId());
$productPrice=$product->getFinalPrice();
```

Comment: i need current price

in this code how can i get current price

Comment: give me time..  i will give u solution

Comment: are you want price of cart or product price or price which  has been shown on product page

Comment: price which has been shown on product page

Comment: when i do  print_r($quote_item);

i got 

`[dimension] => 10.7 x 1.23 x 7.7 inches (WxHxD) [model] => VGN-TXN27N/B [processor] => Intel Core Solo Processor U1500 [memory] => 2 GB RAM [hardrive] => 100 GB Hard Drive [screensize] => 9 inches [short_description] => TXN27N/B notebook PC. [custom_layout_update] => [price] => 2699.9900 [cost] => 899.9900 [weight] => 2.8000 [minimal_price] => 2699.9900 [group_price] => Array ( ) [group_price_changed] => 0 [tier_price] `

Comment: so how can i echo --> [price] attribute

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `sales_quote_add_item` I would recommend using `catalog_product_get_final_price`,it's not only fired when product gets added to the cart but also when the product page is loaded (of course without selected options and qty in this case).

In this observer you can set the price like this:

```
$observer->getProduct()->setFinalPrice($this->getNewPrice());
```